# LibCurl : Upload file to azure blob storage and Authorization

Tags: c, azure, authentication, libcurl, azure-blob-storage

I have to check the network upload speed as well as upload a file in azure blob storage.

Initially I have tried with some sample HTTP servers to check the network speed and it's working. But when I am trying to send the file to azure blob storage HTTP endpoint,  I am not sure how to use the SAS token for the authentication or the username and password will be enough to do the authentication and proceed with further procedure.

I have attached the code I have written , Please give some examples or reliable link for the authentication with SAS token and file upload.

```
size_t uploadspeed()
 {
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE *hd_src;
  struct stat file_info;
  curl_off_t fsize;
  size_t speed_upload, total_time1;

  hd_src = fopen("bbb.txt", "rb");  
  curl = curl_easy_init();
 if(curl) {

int old_stdout = dup(2);
freopen("/dev/null" , "w+" , stderr);
FILE *f = fopen("target.txt", "wb");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, f);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                 "AZURE_URL");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "A:B");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);


curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,(curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);    
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
fclose(stderr);

 if(res != CURLE_OK) {
     fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
else {
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD, &speed_upload);
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &total_time1);


}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
fclose(hd_src);
curl_global_cleanup();
return speed_upload;
}
}
```

Comment: Anyone got any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Sumana, sorry for the late response, you should consider looking at this [**documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)

**Here's an example using SAS with block blob using C#**:

```
    string sasUri = "https://storagesample.blob.core.windows.net/sample-container/" +
    "sampleBlob.txt?sv=2015-07-08&sr=b&sig=39Up9JzHkxhUIhFEjEH9594DJxe7w6cIRCg0V6lCGSo%3D" +
    "&se=2016-10-18T21%3A51%3A37Z&sp=rcw";

CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(sasUri));

// Create operation: Upload a blob with the specified name to the container.
// If the blob does not exist, it will be created. If it does exist, it will be overwritten.
try
{
    MemoryStream msWrite = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blobContent));
    msWrite.Position = 0;
    using (msWrite)
    {
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(msWrite);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Create operation succeeded for SAS {0}", sasUri);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
catch (StorageException e)
{
    if (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == 403)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create operation failed for SAS {0}", sasUri);
        Console.WriteLine("Additional error information: " + e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.